# Google Sheets search and select from Database

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

i'm trying to make a advanced search but i'm stuck at all. I tried it with =SVERWEIS and also with INDEX but failed.

I hope the doc explains enough what I wanna try to do but failed at all. My knowlege isn't that bad but here I need help. Would be nice if someone could help me with this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BGFzntBg-YHcRHM0qChFg9yoLahoOTUehoV3_9DY9PU/edit?usp=sharing

This is the doc and can be edited.

Thanks for your time reading my bad english post. :)

https://prnt.sc/t7c85l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A3:A; D:H; MATCH(B2; D2:H2; 0); 0))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gY8H2NceD22yNiissFuPs0GRq2q5H7VA5ZTz6KrYfKY/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1):

You can write formula as given below -

=if($B$2=E2;E5;0) + if($B$2=F2;F5;0) +if($B$2=G2;G5;0)+if($B$2=H2;H5;0).

Copy this formula in B5 cell in your sheet and try to change the filter from B2 cell.

You can extend this formula for 400 fields.

Comment: The problem is when I go with this =if($B$2=E2;E3;0) I can't search for A3 you understand what I mean?

Comment: For B3, formula will be =if($B$2=E2;E3;0) + if($B$2=F2;F3;0) +if($B$2=G2;G3;0)+if($B$2=H2;H3;0)

Comment: I did understand this formula, thanks for that but as I changed right now the rows are not the same anymore and it gets the wrong values. That's why I wanted to search even for A3/A4/A5 and so on the get the value from the database.

Comment: Here is the updated formula for cell B3, =IF($B$2=E2;VLOOKUP(A3;D3:E20;2;0);0) + IF($B$2=F2;VLOOKUP(A3;D3:F20;3;0);0) + IF($B$2=G2;VLOOKUP(A3;D3:G20;4;0);0) + IF($B$2=H2;VLOOKUP(A3;D3:H20;5;0);0)